# Previously working Java servlet now no longer working after 'Clean' - Tomcat v7.0 and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

So I had an Eclipse project given to me, which I opened in Eclipse and converted to a web project and began writing a servlet + JSP pages for it. It was working fine, until this morning when I cleaned the project using Eclipse's in-built clean function.
Now I am getting the 404 with 'Requested resource is not available' where it was working fine before.
Here is the Servlet code:

```
package servlets;

import is2.data.SentenceData09;
import is2.lemmatizer.Lemmatizer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class FYPServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/FYPServlet")
public class FYPServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public FYPServlet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(request.getParameter("sentence")!=null){

        //Create container
        SentenceData09 sentence = new SentenceData09();

        //Split input up
        String[] words = request.getParameter("sentence").split(" ");
        String lastword = words[words.length-1];
        int sizeoflastword = lastword.length();

        //If sentence has a full stop, remove it
        if(lastword.charAt(sizeoflastword-1)=='.'){
            words[words.length-1] = lastword.substring(0,sizeoflastword-1);
        }

        //Add <root> to start and a full stop to end
        String[] fullsentencewords = new String[words.length+2];
        fullsentencewords[0] = "<root>";
        int i=1;
        for(String word : words){
            fullsentencewords[i] = word;
            i++;
        }
        fullsentencewords[fullsentencewords.length-1] = ".";

        //Initialise the container
        sentence.init(fullsentencewords);

        //Give lemmatizer location of model
        is2.lemmatizer.Options optsLemmatizer = new is2.lemmatizer.Options(new String[] {"-model","C:/Users/Illuria/Downloads/small-models-english/small-models-english/models/lemmatizer-eng-4M-v36.mdl"});

        //Create lemmatizer
        Lemmatizer lemmatizer = new Lemmatizer(optsLemmatizer);

        //Apply the lemmatizer
        lemmatizer.apply(sentence);

        //Display the lemmata
        for (String l : sentence.plemmas) System.out.println("lemma : "+l); //TODO: Push this to the new page

        request.setAttribute("lemmas", sentence.plemmas);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("ParseDisplay.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else{
        response.sendRedirect("EntryForm.jsp");
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request,response);
}
```

The exact 404 I am getting is:
HTTP Status 404 - /mate-tools-2/FYPServlet
type: Status report
message: /mate-tools-2/FYPServlet
description: The requested resource is not available

Unfortunately I'm a bit of a newbie at web development so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about servlet-mappings?

Comment: It's Tomcat v7.0 and the Servlet has @WebServlet so it's mapped appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are still having trouble but sometimes just cleaning wont help. I remove webapp from Tomcat eclipse (right click on Tomcat and do 'Add or Remove'), clean it and add it back. Let us know if this helps.